# scipy convert from matlab ,error: arrays must have same number of dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, scipy

I have this code in MATLAB:

```
ext = [lat(end, :); lat; lat(1, :)];
lat = [ext(:, end) ext ext(:, 1)];
```

and I tried to do this in SciPy:

```
ext = sc.vstack([[lat[-1,:]], [lat], [lat[0,:]]])
lat = sc.vstack([[ext[:]], [ext], [ext[:,0]]])
```

but it gives me the errors:

> ValueError: arrays must have same number of dimensions

and:

> return _nx.concatenate(map(atleast_2d,tup),0) --> (in /usr/lib/pymodules... it's the definition of vstack function)

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stacking vertically in `ext` and horizontally in `lat`.

Try:

```
ext = sc.vstack([lat[-1,:], lat, lat[0,:]])
lat = sc.hstack([ext[:,-1], ext, ext[:,0]])
```

EDIT:

The code above will only work if `lat` is originally a matrix, rather than an array. If that's not the case, you can convert by `lat = sc.matrix(lat)`. Also note that I eliminated the extra square brackets in the argument to `hstack` and `vstack`.

Comment: :Perfect now!Thanks! (as an array is hard to do it or it can't?)

Comment: @George, as an array you would have to reshape intermediate steps for the hstack, as the slicing of an array does not carry the dimentionality information from the original. It will be uglier in my opinion.